# Uso de .. en arrays C#

Tags: c#, array, string

Hola a todos los que lean este post. En unos ejercicios me tope con esta peculiaridad en los arrays de C#.
A lo cual quiero saber ¿Cuál es la función o que significa el uso de [..] en los arrays?.

```
public static string Message(string logLine) =>
        logLine[(logLine.IndexOf(':') + 1)..].Trim();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Esto esta especificado en c# 8... no lo encontraste, o no entendiste la explicacion?

Comment: Es una pregunta interesante. En pocas palabras permite indicar un rango y así obtener una porción de una colección. De manera similar a lo que podrías hacer con `Substring` en el caso de un `string` o  `Range` de Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un operador para definir [rangos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges), en especial (pero no únicamente) para las colecciones que tienen índices (incluyendo los `string`) es decir para todo lo que puedes usar `Objeto[indice]` ahora en vez del índice puedes colocar un rango y te devuelve una sub colección

Se compone de `[inicio..final]`, donde es importante destacar que inicio es inclusive y final es excluyente, es decir la sub colección parte desde inicio y llega hasta uno antes de final

Ejemplo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] lista = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6, 7 ,8 ,9 };
    PrintLista(lista[2..5]); //2, 3 4
    PrintLista(lista[..3]);  //0,1,2
    PrintLista(lista[3..]);  //3, 4, 5, 6 , 7 ,8 ,9
    PrintLista(lista[..]);  //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
}
static void PrintLista(int[] lista)
    => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lista));
```

Como notarás en los ejemplos anteriores los elementos iniciales y finales son opcionales, al no colocarlos se asume que se tiene el primer y el ultimo+1 (el largo) respectivamente.

Además existe el operador hat `^` que hace que los índices se cuenten desde el final al principio (orden inverso)

Ejemplo

```
PrintLista(lista[2..^5]);   //2, 3, 4
PrintLista(lista[..^3]);    //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
PrintLista(lista[^6..^3]);  //4, 5, 6
```

**¿Solo sirven para eso?**

No, porque son básicamente es azúcar sintáctico para Range, entonces es posible usarlo para determinar un rango numérico. Por ejemplo si quisiéramos una función que determina si un número se encuentra dentro de un rango

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(InRange(2, 1..3)); //True
    Console.WriteLine(InRange(4, 1..3)); //False
}
static bool InRange(int numero, Range rango)
    => numero >= rango.Start.Value && numero<rango.End.Value;
```

Mas información en :
(Gracias a @Mateo)

- [Member access operators and expressions - the dot, indexer, and invocation operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator)
- [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)

---

Otro uso interesante que me gustaría mencionar es la implementación de un iterador similar al [range](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/) de Python

*(Nota: Esto lo vi en algún lado, pero no pude recordar donde, no es de mi autoría)*

Creamos una método de extensión y una estructura de esta manera:

```
public static class Extensiones
{
    public static Rango GetEnumerator(this Range rango) => new Rango(rango);
    public static Rango GetEnumerator(this int final) => new Rango(new Range(0,final));
}

public ref struct Rango
{
    public int final { get; set; }
    public int Current { get; set; }
    public Rango(Range r)
    {
        final = r.End.Value;
        Current = r.Start.Value-1;
    }
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        Current++;
        return Current < final; 
    }
}
```

Y luego podemos hacer:

```
foreach(var i in 4..10)
    Console.WriteLine(i); // 4 5 6 7 8 9

foreach (var i in ..5)
    Console.WriteLine(i); // 0 1 2 3 4

foreach (var i in 4)
    Console.WriteLine(i); // 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: [Propuesta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges), [lista de operadores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator) y [tutorial de rangos e índices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes).

Comment: Acabo de recordar que en C# existe algo similar a los rangos de python, [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) por si te interesa.